# Match string against list of RegEx rules using switch...case statement

Tags: c#, fiddler, jscript.net

I've a code snippet written in JScript.Net for FiddlerScript and trying to re-write the same in C# to use as Fiddler extension. I'm not familiar with C# syntax, so need help.

Here's the existing code snippet in JScript.NET, which I'm trying to convert into C#:

```
var sHostname = oSession.hostname;

switch(sHostname) {
    case /example1.com/i.test(sHostname) && sHostname:
    case /example2.com/i.test(sHostname) && sHostname:
    case /example3.com/i.test(sHostname) && sHostname:
        MessageBox.Show("Matched: " + sHostname);
    default:
        FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString("No match for hostname.");
}
```

Here's something I tried in C#, but this is very primitive:

```
var sHostname = oSession.hostname;
string[] patterns = { @"[a-z]", @"[0-9]", @"example[0-9]", @"[a-z0-9.]", @"\w+" }; // a collection of about 20K+ pattern entries, yes 20K+, and stored in separate class
IList<string> patternList = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(patterns);

var status = false;
var pattern = "";
foreach (string p in patternList)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(sHostname, p, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
    {
        pattern = p;
        status = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (status)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Matched: " + pattern);
    // Other code
} else
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No match found");
    // Other code
}
```

As a newbie to C#, I came across many stuff:

- Regex compiled version is better than creating new object every time. I'm not sure specifying switches `RegexOptions::Compiled | RegexOptions::IgnoreCase` will be same as creating the list once and using over iterations. Any hint on this will be helpful.
- Usage of LINQ instead of boilerplate code.
- And many more good things in C# world

All I'm interested is a match or not (boolean true / false value), like Any() and not performing any match, split, etc. Again, this code need to be executed over several hundred times per second in Fiddler, so it need to be efficient enough to match against over 20K+ patterns list for a specified input string. I know it sounds bit crazy, so need help from experts.

FYI, I'm using Visual Studio 2013, so not sure if I can use C# 7 syntax. I'd be very much interested if better things can be done in C# 7 or higher VS versions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far in C# that isn't working? Stackoverflow is not a coding service, the idea is that you try things yourself first.

Comment: The C# [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#pattern) statement is not as flexible as in other languages. Use a chained `if`/`else if` or in this case, `if` with `&&` instead. PS And that code isn't very well written - too much testing of `sHostname`.

Comment: Show more code for the actual problem! I can't tell what you really need from this, as most the time regex is the wrong choice.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I edited the description and added the last working code snippet. Regex is the only option I figured out, and can't get around it with other things like contains, etc. I've to leverage the collection of regex patterns from past, and have to find an efficient code to use the same. Thank you for your understanding and please help.